# Error line: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, inflate-exception

I tried doing a Drawing application in my android studio but when I tried running it on my Phone or to the emulator. The app just suddenly stops.Here is the copy of my content_main activity xml file on Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/new_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/start_new"
        android:src="@drawable/new_pic" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/brush"
        android:src="@drawable/brush" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/erase_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/erase"
        android:src="@drawable/eraser" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/save_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/save"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/paint_colors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF660000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="#FF660000"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFF0000" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF6600"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFF6600" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFCC00"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFFCC00" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF009900"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF009900" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF009999"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF009999" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Bottom Row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF0000FF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF990099"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF990099" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF6666"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFF6666" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF787878"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF787878" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FF000000" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Full LogCat results when I tried to run the emulator

```
03-20 14:16:47.259 2807-2807/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already     on)
03-20 14:16:47.259 2807-2807/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
03-20 14:16:47.283 2807-2807/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
03-20 14:16:47.315 2807-2814/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-20 14:16:47.315 2807-2814/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-20 14:16:47.321 2807-2807/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview-2/lib/x86
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process:     com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview, PID: 2807
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException:         Unable to start activity                ComponentInfo{com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview/com.example.chadymaebarina    n.drawingview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file     line #19: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class     com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line     #10: Error inflating class com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class     "com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file     "/data/app/com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview-    2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=    [/data/app/com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at     android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:            ... 27 more
03-20 14:16:47.355 2807-2807/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
03-20 14:16:50.535 2807-2807/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2807 SIG: 9
```

Have no Idea, how to fix this code. I think it has something to do with my layout file.

```
<com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

But I don't know :( Please tell me how to fix the errors. Thank you so much!

Update: Here is my drawingview class

package com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class DrawingView extends View {
private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing(){
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
//get drawing area setup for interaction
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
//view given size
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
//draw view
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//detect user touch
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;

    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public void setColor(String newColor){
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
//set color
}
}
```

Comment: Post code of your class :`com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview`

Comment: If you work the way down the stack trace you'll see : `AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class     "com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file     "/data/app/com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview-  `  etc.. This is the root problem

Comment: @dieter_h Just finished updating. :)

Comment: @MarkKeen Oh Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the classname on your XML

Your **package name** is `com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview`... So you get a ClassNotFoundException.

Change your XML to use the full name of the DrawingView class.

```
<com.example.chadymaebarinan.drawingview.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement 3 constructors of your class not one.

```
public DrawingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
        setupDrawing();
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
        setupDrawing();
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setupDrawing();
}
```

If not help try debug `DrawingView` class code.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You just copied the constructor that was already defined

Comment: Adding constructors doesn't solve the exception, though